# possible to update commons lib dependencies in play 2.1?

Tags: sbt, apache-commons, playframework-2.1

I'm running into a problem referencing new(er) versions of the commons-codec lib in my Play 2.1.3 project.

I've added the maven dependency reference to my project's Build.scala file:

"commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.6"

When I run play dependencies everything looks fine. However, when I run my app I get compilation errors saying that one of the methods can't be found (a variant of md5Hex introduced in v1.4 of commons-codec).

After exploration it appears that commons-codec 1.3 is being pulled in by other libs (either SBT or httpclient perhaps?). Even after blowing away my play/repository directory and rebuilding.

I'm curious if it's possible to reference newer versions of commons libs from within a project. If so how can I ensure that my application links against the correct version? I would have thought that play dependencies would have shown what's happening internally, however, it appears to be significantly more complicated.

-- UDPATE --

Ok, after further research it appears that this is specific to commons-codec, which is being required by other Play referenced libs. It appears they require v1.3 specifically, which is some how overriding my requirement for 1.6?!

This mess aside I was able to update commons-io as expected.

Comment: `commons-codec` is pulled-in by some of play's dependencies, but it should be overridable by your own dependencies. Can you show how you add your `1.6` dependency in `Build.scala`?

Comment: @gourlaysama looking back at the steps i attempted now, it appears i used the standard maven include in the Build.scala file: "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.6"  Running play dependencies showed the correct version but compilation failed as one of new the methods in 1.6 wasn't present.